# How to wget all Betacoronavirus .tar.gz files from BLAST database directory?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to use wget to download all Betacoronavirus files ending in .tar.gz from https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/. I can use wget and paste in the link to a single one of those files, and it will download that just fine. But when I try to use some sort of regex, e.g. something with Betacoronavirus.*.tar.gz to download them all at once for me, it doesn't work. I've tried multiple things I've seen on some other threads, but still, none work.

Comment: Different method, similar outcome (compare: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)): looks like these files are available via FTP under `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/`, so you can use [`curlftpfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1292278/432690) and work with them as if they were local (e.g. `cd mountpoint && cp Betacoronavirus.*.tar.gz /somewhere/`). Note this only works because the server provides FTP access. There is FUSE for HTTP(S), but since there is no notion of listable directories in HTTP, you cannot mount `db/` and get files from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a protocol designed for transferring files rather than text. In this case, the hostname "ftp" suggests you can also access the resources via FTP. wget can glob via FTP:

```
wget 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:21/blast/db/Betacoronavirus.*.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "regex" or "glob" `Betacoronavirus.*.tar.gz` on the wget command-line, **it is getting executed on your local machine** in your Current Working Directory.

`wget Betacoronavirus.*.tar.gz`

In that Directory, there may be no such file  and the "glob" is empty ; Alternatively, the Directory may contain some already downloaded file, then the "glob" may match that and try to download the same file.

**Either way, that will not work.**

What you require is a glob on the **remote ftp machine**. You can get that by using **a cli ftp client**.
Your best way (simple way) would be to use a **gui ftp client and select the matching files and click download**. I recommend **WinSCP & FileZilla**.

Advanced way would be to download the html source for the Directory Listing, Parse it and take out the matching files and execute wget on each matching file. I do not recommend this, given your use case.